# Android Logcat error message.

Tags: android

These error messages appear when I run my Application. It doesn't affect the execution of the application though. The app is based on Android 4 ( API Level 14), it has some code to call a web service, and the build path has http-commons library.

```
02-12 10:39:11.110: E/AndroidRuntime(661): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to            instantiate application android.app.Application: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-12 10:39:11.110: E/AndroidRuntime(661):  at   android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:482)
02-12 10:39:11.110: E/AndroidRuntime(661):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3909)
02-12 10:39:11.110: E/AndroidRuntime(661):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:122)
02-12 10:39:11.110: E/AndroidRuntime(661):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1184)
02-12 10:39:11.110: E/AndroidRuntime(661):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-12 10:39:11.110: E/AndroidRuntime(661):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
02-12 10:39:11.110: E/AndroidRuntime(661):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
02-12 10:39:11.110: E/AndroidRuntime(661):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method ) 
02-12 10:39:11.110: E/AndroidRuntime(661):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-12 10:39:11.110: E/AndroidRuntime(661):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-12 10:39:11.110: E/AndroidRuntime(661):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-12 10:39:11.110: E/AndroidRuntime(661):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-12 10:39:11.110: E/AndroidRuntime(661): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-12 10:39:11.110: E/AndroidRuntime(661):  at android.app.LoadedApk.initializeJavaContextClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:362)
02-12 10:39:11.110: E/AndroidRuntime(661):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:305)
02-12 10:39:11.110: E/AndroidRuntime(661):  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:474)
02-12 10:39:11.110: E/AndroidRuntime(661):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Strange error. Seems like a problem with your application setup

Answer (score 1):

If you google for [initializeJavaContextClassLoader NullPointerException](http://www.google.nl/search?hl=nl&q=initializeJavaContextClassLoader%20npe#sclient=psy-ab&hl=nl&tbm=dsc&source=hp&q=initializeJavaContextClassLoader%20NullPointerException&pbx=1&oq=initializeJavaContextClassLoader%20NullPointerException&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=5596l8047l0l8482l20l18l0l0l0l0l158l1902l9.9l18l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=ba0b4a9312673dc8&biw=1366&bih=594) you'll find you are definitely not the only one running into this. The solution isn't really clear though.

Have you tried doing a Project -> Clean and rebuilding?

Comment: Yes I tried 'clean and rebuild' with no success. The weird thing is that sometimes the app runs without generating the error!