# What are these errors in Android Logcat ? My app works fine so : why these errors?

Tags: android, logcat

When running an Android application, I get these errors, but everything actually works fine on the device. What's that means? And how to get rid of them ?

```
07-20 11:09:38.119: E/AndroidRuntime(930): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-20 11:09:38.119: E/AndroidRuntime(930): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application android.app.Application: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-20 11:09:38.119: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:482)
07-20 11:09:38.119: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3909)
07-20 11:09:38.119: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:122)
07-20 11:09:38.119: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1184)
07-20 11:09:38.119: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-20 11:09:38.119: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-20 11:09:38.119: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
07-20 11:09:38.119: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-20 11:09:38.119: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-20 11:09:38.119: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-20 11:09:38.119: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-20 11:09:38.119: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-20 11:09:38.119: E/AndroidRuntime(930): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-20 11:09:38.119: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  at android.app.LoadedApk.initializeJavaContextClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:362)
07-20 11:09:38.119: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:305)
07-20 11:09:38.119: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:474)
07-20 11:09:38.119: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Your app works after a Fatal Exception!!!??

Comment: Yes ! That's why I'm wondering why all these errors appeared ! Maybe a timeout ?...

Comment: Can you check `line 362` where `NullPointerException` is raised in your _LoadedApk.java_?

Comment: + java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application android.app.Application ?! Are you sure you are not just running an earlier version of the app, that worked or something? Do these errors appear every time you run the app?

Comment: It just appeared, and did not appeared before, while I changed nothing in my Activities that could throw these Exceptions!

Comment: @Abhilasha How do you check this ? Where is LoadedApk.java ?

Comment: this is android framwork file....

Comment: Yes I guess, so how could I do the link with my code ?

Comment: Does anyone have the solution. I am having the same EXACT issue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()`. You have set an application-level error handler, which is printing stacktrace to the log.

This is why your app runs on after throwing a **Fatal Exception**.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are asking here. Your app is not working fine, your app throws a `nullpointerexception`. This is NOT fine.

Take a look at this line.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-20 11:09:38.119: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  at android.app.LoadedApk.initializeJavaContextClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:362)
```

Now I'm assuming your own classes/files are not named like this, and if you check for that `initializeJavaContextClassLoader` you find a lot of things. It looks like this is more of a "settings" or emulator thing then a code thing.

There are some other questions (you could call them duplicates even?) around:

- [Android Logcat error message.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247603/android-logcat-error-message)
- [Android - exception when compiling and running the application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9833336/android-exception-when-compiling-and-running-the-application)
- [Android App is crashing when installing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390361/android-app-is-crashing-when-installing)

THey all imply that this is something not code-specific, and it might have to do with your settings.

A clean etc is always advicable, but that doesn't seem to help with all. best you can do as far as I can see is to try and do a clean and build of your project.

Comment: The questions you mention are effectively duplicates. But the people don't seem to know the origin, and for some the app stills runs, and for others it crashes.

Comment: I <b>uninstalled the app</b>, then did a <b>clean</b>. I don'tget these errors when launching for the first time, but still get these errors when launching after.